# Is it legal to assign a member to another member in a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Is assigning `m_B` to `m_A` in the constructor below legal, provided that `m_B` is declared after `m_A`?

```
class C {
    int m_A, m_B;
    C() : m_A(0), m_B(m_A) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is legal to assign a member to another member in a constructor. There is an example in the standard (§ 15.6.2/15 )

> ```
> class X {
>     int a;
>     int b;
>     int i;
>     int j;
> public:
>     const int& r;
>     X(int i): r(a), b(i), i(i), j(this->i) { }
> };
> ```

Note that the data members are initialized in the order they are declared in the class definition. The order of the member initializers doesn't matter. 
So, the below is valid

```
class C {
    int m_A, m_B;
    C() : m_B(m_A), m_A(0) {}     // Swapped the member initialization order.
};
```

but this isn't valid

```
class C {
        int m_B, m_A;             // Swapped the declaration order.
        C() : m_B(m_A), m_A(0) {}
    };
```

Comment: Does the order of members matter? Or the order they appear in on initializer list?

Comment: They're initialized in the order of declaration in the class definition, regardless of the order of the initializer list. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order

Comment: @orhtej2; § 15.6.2/13.3: *Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers)*

Comment: @orhtej2; Added example to make it more clear.